# How can I get Camera Altitude in MapBox GL JS?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I know that using

```
const camera = map.getFreeCameraOptions();

const cameraPosition = camera._position.toLngLat();
```

I can get at cameraPosition the longitude and latitude from the camera, but what about the elevation/altitude?
What exactly is then, following the previous code:

```
const elevation = camera._elevation;
```

And why is always with the value `undefined`?

How can I get the correct altitude value?

Thanks in advance,

Joan.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

`const altitude = camera._position.toAltitude();`

In the future, you can do `console.log(camera._position);` and inspect the available methods and attributes that show up in the console for the specified object. This is how I found it.